# Issue in opening existing project in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, freeze

I am working on `Android Studio 1.0.1` on Windows machine. When I create a new project then it is working fine but when I am trying to import or open any other project then it hangs up the android studio and after sometime black screen appears in android studio.
To get rid of this, I have to forcefully kill Android Studio.

Kindly help in case anyone found same issue. There is no error , even no Gradle progress in showing at bottom.

Comment: What about first update to the latest version? I think it's 1.5.1 by now

Comment: ok lemme try that as well. but it was working on 1.0.1 on other system

Comment: updating android studio works for me. Thanks Desdroid

Comment: Good to hear. I wrote an answer, so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is problem with the allocated heap size for Android studio.
Try to increase the -Xmx and -Xms value in **stdudio.exe.vmoptions** or **stdudio64.exe.vmoptions** file at below path:

1. for Windows the file path is [INSTALL-LOCATION]\bin (eg. C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin)
2. for Mac the file path will be something like :
   /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions.

keep values something like:
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
or more if you have sufficient RAM.

Comment: i increased VM option from settings in android studio but in vain :(

Comment: cane you once try to incearse values at this location as well?? :
%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions.

The documentation tells that userprofiles values may superceed the installation values : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Answer (score 0):

As already written as a comment, you should keep your tools up to date. 
Therefore kindly update to the latest version of Android Studio.

While it should've worked on 1.0.1 as well, it is hard to find the error, when there is no error output.